# NameError: name 'uuid_generate_v4' is not defined

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

Getting this error while running insert query with uuid as primary key.

> "NameError: name 'uuid_generate_v4' is not defined"

Note: extension 'uuid-ossp' is already created.

Is there any import statement I am missing?

This is the insert statement i am using

```
postgres_insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (UUID_ID,FULLNAME) VALUES (%s,%s)"

  record_to_insert =(uuid_generate_v4(),'name')

  cur.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)

  connection.commit()
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem and post the full error traceback!

Comment: It is a function `uuid_generate_v4()`.

Comment: updated my question. I was using the uuid_generate_v4() method to generate uuid

Comment: `"INSERT INTO users (UUID_ID,FULLNAME) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(),%s)"` and pass only one argument to it. `uuid_generate_v4` is a postgres function, but you use it inside Python. And AFAIK you cannot pass a function call as an argument. There's no point in doing that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the function call as part of the SQL statement instead of as a parameter. Something like:

```
postgres_insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (UUID_ID,FULLNAME) select uuid_generate_v4(),%s"

  record_to_insert =('name')

  cur.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)

  connection.commit()
```